# VBScript - Object doesn't support this property or method: DateCreated

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to use this property in VBScript: DateCreated, as described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke6a7czx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx

But I get the following error:
Microsoft VBSCript runtime error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method: 'objFSO.DateCreated'

I cannot find any information on the internet, can somebody help?

This is a piece of my code:

```
Function showFile( str )
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objReadFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( str , 1, False)

    contents = objReadFile.ReadAll
    objReadFile.close

    strCreated= objFSO.DateCreated
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 7):

You're not getting a `File` or `Folder` object in your code, but you're trying to invoke the method on the `FileSystemObject` (the ActiveX Component itself).

You need to get a `File` object for a specific file name to invoke `DateCreated` on as described in the MSDN sample code on the page you linked in your question:

```
Dim fso, f
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFile(filespec)
ShowFileInfo = "Created: " & f.DateCreated
```

They are calling `GetFile` on the `FileSystemObject` to actually get the `File` object.